# Nodemailer SMTP connection refused error (NodeJS server)

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to send an email via my NodeJS server using the nodemailer npm library and I am encountering a connection error.

Here is my NodeJS server code describing the configuration of my nodemailer smtp. The function is being triggered over an https connection to my NodeJS server.

```
const smtpTransport = createTransport({
        host: "smtp.mailtrap.io",
        port: 2525,
        secure: true,
        debug: true,
        logger: true,
        tls: {
            // do not fail on invalid certs
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        },
        auth: {
            user: "24a411cb3f5900",
            pass: "2b78eab080e46d"
        }
    });

    smtpTransport.verify(function(error, success) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
        }
    });

    const mail = getEmailData(mailDetails, type);

    smtpTransport.sendMail(mail, function(error, response) {
        console.log("sendmail breakpoint"); // Breakpoint logged then connection error encountered
        if(error) {
            console.log(error)
        } else {
            console.log( " email sent successfully")
        }
        smtpTransport.close();
    })
```

When I trigger the sendEmail action via an axios.post() to my https: NodeJS server, I get the following error:

```
App 424656 output: sendmail breakpoint
App 424656 output: { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 3.209.246.195:2525
App 424656 output:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
App 424656 output:   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
App 424656 output:   code: 'ESOCKET',
App 424656 output:   syscall: 'connect',
App 424656 output:   address: '3.209.246.195',
App 424656 output:   port: 2525,
App 424656 output:   command: 'CONN' }
```

I need help figuring out what exactly is going wrong in the process.

Comment: Using `secure: false,` I can connect successfully to the server. You also posted your actual credentials on the internet, so I can now send out messages in your name.

Comment: Yea its mailtrap.io, you actually can send messages using those credentials but they will be trapped in my inbox

Comment: `secure : false` doesn't work if you are sending via an https connection

Comment: I got an error about ssl3 / wrong version when I tried `secure: true`; I googled the error and found that unless you actually use port 465/587, you're supposed to use `secure: false`. And it worked immediately.

Comment: It still gives me a connection error (sorry for the late reply)

Comment: No idea why; here's the output I'm getting: https://pastebin.com/7KCvrV1e